# How can SQLiteOpenHelper return SQLiteDatabase?

Tags: java, android

I know that **SQLiteDatabase** doesn't have any public constructor and I cannot create its object directly.

But then how is **SQLiteOpenHelper** able to return **SQLiteDatabase** reference using **getReadableDatabase()** or **getWritableDatabase()**?

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html I assume the `createDatabase` and `openDatabase` functions call the private (or protected, not sure) constructor of `SQLiteDatabase`, since the static functions are declared in `SQLiteDatabase`. `SQLiteOpenHelper` internally calls those.

Comment: @Jakar Can you show me some demo Java code to understand you answer?

Comment: the code for SQLiteDatabase and SQLiteOpenHelper is open source, you can check out how it works.

Comment: see http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java#SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase%28java.lang.String%2Candroid.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory%2Cint%29 in particular

Comment: @Barun, If you haven't accepted an answer in a few hours, I'll post some example code to explain how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because the constructor isn't public/visible doesn't mean it doesn't exist!

`SQLiteOpenHelper` uses `SQLiteDatabase`'s static constructor `openDatabase` to create a new database instance.  It is public and has not been hidden so, although it is probably not a good idea, you could call it, directly, yourself.

According to the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openDatabase(java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int,%20android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)) you would use it like this:

```
   SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null);
```

The first argument is a String giving the full path name for the new db.  The second is the cursor factory.  Passing null for the second arg will get you the default factory.

Using the `SQLiteOpenHelper` guarantees that the db is correctly created and correctly initialized.  It also properly caches db instances, so that they aren't recreated every time you need them.  It is probably better to use it.

Comment: although `SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase` is not actually a constructor, I don't know how we should call it. I am not sure `static constructor` is the best term.

Comment: @njzk2  If it works for Joshua Bloch, it works for me.

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike After looking at the source files at `android-sdk/sources/android-19/android/database/sqlite`, I believe your answer is the correct one.

Comment: Thank you @Barun!  Looking at the source code is how I arrived at it!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Class Cdb.java:

```
public class Cdb extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "db_name.db";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    Cdb(Context context) {
        super(context.getApplicationContext(), DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        // Upgrade here
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);

}
```

and then you may access the database as follows:

```
Cdb openHelper = new Cdb(this);
SQLiteDatabase db = openHelper.getReadableDatabase();
```

Comment: Your code is already shown in Android documentation and I understand it but what I wanted to know is any Java-related reason for getting reference that way.

Comment: @Barun the reason to it this way is so all your db create/ upgrade code is in one file.  Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440195/how-to-invoke-onupgrade-in-android-for-work-with-sqlite-database/22444918#22444918  and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793004/android-sqlite-database-why-drop-table-and-recreate-on-upgrade/19836980#19836980